# Bitbucket - Error with loading content / different in Pull Requests

Tags: bitbucket

From yesterday I have got more often error message on content / different in Pull Requests:

> Error
>
> We were unable to load this page.

All commits history is properly display - but it cannot load different between branches.

I looking for solution - but [this issue](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/10903/we-were-unable-to-load-this-page) is only what I found.

Have anybody similar problem?

---

**UPDATE**

Ok in [this one](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/14560/we-were-unable-to-load-this-page) I found that cause is:

> This issue (and related issues linked above) where caused by a brief storage issue that has been resolved. Our apologies for the inconvenience.

as `Alastair Wilkes` said - staff from bitbucket.

But this problem is still apearing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referring to the incident mentioned in https://status.bitbucket.org/incidents/11x16h559cl1 ?

Comment: Yes, I think this is same incident.